# How to enable users to edit HtmlFieldControl source in TFS 2015 on-premise?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

If you insert an image into the 'Description' HtmlFieldControl when editing a work item, then the html img src attribute will have an absolute url like `<img src='http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/dc/_api/_wit/DownloadAttachment?fileGuid=03e65645..." .. >`

Images then wont be shown when working with a reverse proxy, where users from outside our company access our tfs with an url like 'https://tfs.mycompany.com/tfs', because from outside there is no access to 'http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs'

My idea is now to convert the absolute url to a relative one, like `<img src='/tfs/dc/_api/_wit/DownloadAttachment?fileGuid=03e65645..." .. >`. After editing the html of the System.Description field manually and save it, the image gets shown properly shown as well from inside tfs users as to external users who use the reverse proxy.

I found out a VSTS extension can react on an onFieldChanged event, and I want to change the img src accordingly in the html of System.Descripton field.

Since TFS 2017 there is a new element called 'WebLayout and Control elements', which would be the perfect approach. Unfortunately, our company still uses TFS 2015 on-premise, and the update will be done not earlier than end of this year.

**So my question is**, can I use an already existing way to develop functionality to provide automatically or manually replace the absolute with the relative url?

**I found no way** to use VSTS extensions **ON** an existing work item form with TFS 2015. And it seems to be impossible to enhance the default HtmlFieldControl. Or could I write a customized HtmlFieldControl?

It is not possible to put another control like 'FieldControl' for System.Description onto the wit form, it's not supported. It would be tedious to edit the html by hand always after inserting an image in the HtmlFieldControl, save it, reload and edit it in the plain FieldControl. But even that would be accepted as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it easy:

```
var descriptionField = that._workItem.getField("System.Description");
var descriptionHTML = descriptionField._getValue().toString();
...
descriptionHTML = descriptionHTML.replace(toReplace,replaceWith);
descriptionField.setValue(descriptionHTML);
```